# Как избежать подключения к классу DB в каждом методе MainModel?

Tags: php

```
abstract class MainModel
{
    const TABLE = '';

    public static function getAll(){
        $dbh = DB::getInstance();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.static::TABLE;
        return $dbh->query($sql);
    }

    public static function getOne($id){
        $dbh = DB::getInstance();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.static::TABLE.' WHERE id='.$id;
        return $dbh->query($sql);
    }
    public static function deleteOne($id){
        $dbh = DB::getInstance();
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM '.static::TABLE.' WHERE id='.$id;
        return $dbh->execute($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: унаследоваться?

Comment: Саму модель не нужно делать статической. Пусть это будет обычный объект, который создается фабрикой. Которая и будет передавать соединение с БД в конструктор

Comment: Вы нарушили принцип SOLID, и это принцип инверсии зависимостей. Ваши методы MainModel неявно зависят от доступности DB и его внутреннего состояния. Вы не можете использовать MainModel без DB, а DB, предположительно, требует соединения с БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static private $connect = null;

static public function getConnect() 
{
    if(!is_null(self::$connect)) {
        return self::$connect;
    }

    self::$connect = DB::getInstance();
    return self::$connect;
}
```

И вообще зачем тут вам статичный класс непонятно...

всё таки я переобразовал его так

```
abstract class MainModel
{
    private $table = null;
    private $connect = null;

    private function __construct()
    {
       $this->_init();
    }

    abstract protected function _init();

    public function getAll(){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$this->getTable();
        return $this->getConnect()->query($sql);
    }

    public function getOne($id){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$this->getTable().' WHERE id='.$id;
        return $this->getConnect()->query($sql);
    }
    public function deleteOne($id){
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM '.$this->getTable().' WHERE id='.$id;
        return $this->getConnect()->execute($sql);
    }

    public function setTable($table) {
       $this->table = $table;
       return $this;
    }

    public function getTable() 
    {
       return $this->table;
    }


    final public function getConnect() 
    {
        if(!is_null($this->connect)) {
           return $this->connect;
        }

        $this->connect = DB::getInstance();
        return $this->connect;
     }
}
```

Comment: На мой вкус здесь те же шары, только в профиль :) Я бы сделал обычную протектед переменную, и соединялся в конструкторе.

Comment: @Ипатьев init вынес что бы он стал абстрактным так как нам его надо переопределять в дочерних класах, чтобы установить ту же табличку, так как конструкторможно и забыть переопределить, а с абстрактным класом и ide подсветит и php error кинет. Про getConnection() на случай еслисильно захочеться из другого класа достать connection и выполнить запрос(звучит не красиво но бывает) да и protected переменной можно не чайно присвоить значение где то в дочерним классе, что тоже приведёт к ошибке.

Comment: @Ипатьев по сути его можно сделать даже финальным, что бы не переопределить